# Unable to boot 11.10 due to graphic driver problem with ati Radeon HD6470M o Amd A8 quad core

Tags: installation, ati

I have been trying to find a solution for a graphics bug  with little luck so far.

Has anybody found the solution to the ati radeon graphics problem?

I have a laptop with Amd A8 with ati Amd Radeon HD 6470M and H6620G I cant boot ubuntu.
I have the latest driver downloaded on flash drive but cant figure out how to get it into the ubuntu programe.

I can't do wget downloaded into root.

Can someone tell me if they have resolved and if so how as there is little point now asking for solutions for part of the problem is someone already resolved the main issue.
I feel really stupid I have a whole bunch of laptops running 11.10 even a netbook. The quadcore I just bought is sitting gathering dust.

Comment: Your graphics card is not listed as supported here: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware In my experience, if it is not listed as supported (by ATI) on that wiki page it does not work. If you do not get a better answer here, you might want to contact ATI or change out the graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

Your card [is not supported](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware) by the Linux driver, there is not much you can do about it. ATI needs to fix that, it is not related to Ubuntu in any ways.

Keep using the open source drivers, they are your only choice at the moment. You system has a hybrid graphics solution that is not supported by the driver yet. You can always complain to ATI and hope that they can solve this, but at the moment there is not much you can do to solve this situation.

You cannot make a driver work if it was not built for your hardware.